# How to transfer a VR button ownership using Photon2?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, photon

I am currently working on a project and I want to use several buttons in my multiplayer game.

Unfortunately the button can only be pushed locally and it's not synced over the network.

For some reasons the game doesn't trigger the script that should transfer the ownership to the player

I don't really know what's going on and why this isn't triggered ...

I already tried to ad photon tranform views on the moving part and the button itself but without results

```cs
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.name == "LHand" || other.name == "RHand")
        {
            ChangeOwnership(other);
        }
        print("trigger entered but not a hand");
    }

    public void ChangeOwnership(Collider col)
    {
        if (GetComponent<PhotonView>().Owner != col.GetComponent<PhotonView>().Owner)
        {
            GetComponent<PhotonView>().TransferOwnership(col.GetComponent<PhotonView>().Owner);
            print("changed ownership to: " + col.GetComponent<PhotonView>().Owner);

        }

    }
```

If the trigger is actually entered this should show the player as the owner and not the scene...

So if someone has a clue about this I'll take it ...